# Calling method on real object instead calling on Mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsf, junit, mockito

I faced next issue when I have been writing Junit tests with using Mockito. My test invokes methods on real object instead mock object and I receive NullPointerException. Here is my code:

```
public class JSFUtilsTest {

    public JSFUtilsTest() { }

    JSFUtils jsfUtils = mock(JSFUtils.class); 
    FacesContext facesContext = ContextMocker.mockFacesContext();    
    ExternalContext extContext = mock(ExternalContext.class);    
    Application app = mock(Application.class);    
    ExpressionFactory exFactory = mock(ExpressionFactory.class);    
    ELContext elContext = mock(ELContext.class);    
    ValueExpression valExp = mock(ValueExpression.class);

    @Test
    public void testResolveExpression() {          
        when(jsfUtils.resolveExpression("expression")).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){                                                                                  
                    when(facesContext.getApplication()).thenReturn(app);
                    when(app.getExpressionFactory()).thenReturn(exFactory);
                    when(facesContext.getELContext()).thenReturn(elContext);
                    when(exFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "expression", Object.class)).thenReturn(valExp);
                    when(valExp.getValue(elContext)).thenReturn(anyObject());
                    return valExp.getValue(elContext);                                                                       
                }
            });

        jsfUtils.resolveExpression(anyString()); 

        verify(jsfUtils).resolveExpression(anyString());        
        assertNotNull(jsfUtils.resolveExpression(anyString()));        
    }

}
```

Instead calling resolveExpression() on Mock, I have got calling on JSFUtils object. JSFUtils.java and JSFUtilsTest.java are located in different packages. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks very confused to be. Typically you might set up your mocks using `when` and `anyString()`, but then you would call the methods with actual strings. You seem to be doing it backwards. Also I'm not sure why your `Answer` method does a bunch more `when` setups. I don't understand how you intend all this to work.

Comment: If you mock the method you are trying to test, then you're not actually testing it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I use anyString() with when and real string in method calling. But I still have my issue with NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is just an example and in real test you do not call methods on the mock directly, but inject the dependencies to OUT.

You are expecting your mock to answer when you are calling `jsfUtils.resolveExpression("expression")`. In fact you are not calling it. I would suggest to change it to `jsfUtils.resolveExpression(anyString())` and if you need it to be called with some specific string, you can check it the verify block: `verify(jsfUtils).resolveExpression("expression");`

Also calling `jsfUtils.resolveExpression(anyString());` is not the right approach. Method `anyString()` is designed for stubbing not for real call.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me how to inject the dependencies to out in my example?

Comment: For instance constructor of your `JsfUtils` class could look something like this `JsfUtils(FacesContext facesContext, ExternalContext extContext *an so on*)`. Of course, it's not good to have 7 dependencies in your class, so you can think about how to split it, but this is another topic. Maybe you don't need this dependencies at all.

Comment: I can see, that you are using all the mock only for calculating the result of `jsfUtils.resolveExpression`. That is not what mocks are supposed to do.

Comment: Yes. I should remake my test methods

Answer (score 0):

> Instead calling resolveExpression() on Mock, I have got calling on JSFUtils object.

Then do not create a mock, but a spy:

```
//JSFUtils jsfUtils = mock(JSFUtils.class); 
JSFUtils jsfUtils = spy(new JSFUtils(/* mocks of dependencies if needed */));
```

But this is only needed if want to mock the return value of some other method in your class under test to force isolation of your unit.

This is not the case in your example as far as I see. So just write:

```
//JSFUtils jsfUtils = mock(JSFUtils.class); 
JSFUtils jsfUtils = new JSFUtils(/* mocks of dependencies if needed */);
```

> ```
> @Test
> public void testResolveExpression() {          
>     when(jsfUtils.resolveExpression("expression")).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
>             public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){                                                                                  
>                 when(facesContext.getApplication()).thenReturn(app);
>                 when(app.getExpressionFactory()).thenReturn(exFactory);
>                 when(facesContext.getELContext()).thenReturn(elContext);
>                 when(exFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "expression", Object.class)).thenReturn(valExp);
>                 when(valExp.getValue(elContext)).thenReturn(anyObject());
>                 return valExp.getValue(elContext);                                                                       
>             }
>         });             
>     jsfUtils.resolveExpression(anyString()); 
>     verify(jsfUtils).resolveExpression(anyString());        
>     assertNotNull(jsfUtils.resolveExpression(anyString()));
> ```

This does not make any sense:
You mock the method of your class under test (cut) and then call that very same method. This way you do not verify the behavior of your cut but the behavior of the mocking framework.

Also you call the method twice within the same test method. You should avoid that.

You should change your test to this:

```
@Test
public void testResolveExpression() {
    // arrange (test case specific setup of mocks and DTOs)
    when(facesContext.getApplication()).thenReturn(app);
    when(app.getExpressionFactory()).thenReturn(exFactory);
    when(facesContext.getELContext()).thenReturn(elContext);
    when(exFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "expression", Object.class)).thenReturn(valExp);
    when(valExp.getValue(elContext)).thenReturn(anyObject());

    // act (call real method on real object)
    Object result = jsfUtils.resolveExpression("a valid input"); 

    // assert
    assertNotNull(result );  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cannot use JSFUtils object, because I need mock FacesContext. When I use JSFUtils instead mock, I receive NullPointerException

Comment: `getFacesContext()` is a static method and must be mocked using *PowerMock(-ito)*. But I just came up with another question: JSFUtil is a class delivered by oracle. Why do *you* want to test it?

Comment: This is my first task for unit testing and I think I'm too carried away :)

Comment: Who was giving you that task? teacher? a coworker? your boss? Starting with a class requiering the use of PowerMock is really hard and does not convey the right "message" IMHO. But at the end you should search SO for "how to mock static method calls?" This has been answered already.

Comment: This task is from my coworker. I must write tests as much as possible. But I think, should not write tests for bean classes, getters and setters and, of course, for OOTB classes.

Comment: @Slava *"I must write tests as much as possible."* If you were *my* coworker I'd expect you to write tests **as good as possible**... / *"But I think, should not write tests for bean classes, getters and setters"* it depends. Some setters have logic and are not **too simple to fail** / *"and, of course, for OOTB classes"* You have to verify **your** (companies) **own code**. It *may* make sense to write a test for a 3rd party class if that lib is still in developement and you heavily depent on a certain behavior of that class, but usually you trust those other libs.